# MISSISSIPPI probability question

Tags: probability

> Find the probability that:
>
> a) The I's occur together, and the P's occur together in the arrangement.
>
> b) The arrangement that starts and ends with the same letter.

So there are a total of 4 I's, 4 S's and 2 P's.

For a) my answer is $\frac{7!}{4!4!2!}$ divided by $\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}$ which gives $P(A) = \frac{7!}{11!}$.

For b) I think the number of combinations that both start and end with I is: $\frac{9!}{4!2!2!}$ (should be the same as number of combinations that start and end with S)
And the number of combinations that start and end with P is: $\frac{9!}{4!4!}$, so $P(B)$ is the number of combinations that start and end with I/P/S added together and divided by $\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}$. Are my steps correct?

Comment: $\dfrac{7!}{4!4!2!}$?  Was that supposed to be a count of something?  Stop and think for a moment... is that even an integer?  No?  Then it can't be right.

Comment: Your answer for (B) is correct (*though unnecessarily complicated, you could do this quicker as $\frac{8}{11}\times\frac{3}{10} + \frac{2}{11}\times\frac{1}{10}$*).  As alluded to already, for (A) you went and did something wrong.  As for a hint for (A), merge all of the $I$'s together and merge all of the $P$'s together.  Now... how many objects are being arranged and how much repetition is going on?  (*Notice, the I's are only a single object now... not four objects.*)

Comment: I take it we're making the assumption that all arrangements are equally likely?